# ready() working, on('ready') not working, why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I tried to use 'on' in my code but failed. The code I tried was this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clickHandler(e) {
      alert('Click!');
    }
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $('#click_me').on('click', clickHandler);
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="click_me" type="button" value="click me" />
</body>

</html>
```

Though I can replace this code with the code below. I still wonder why my first code with the event `on` didn't work.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clickHandler(e) {
      alert('Click!');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#click_me').click(clickHandler);
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="click_me" type="button" value="click me" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because the first one does not exist. It's document.ready not on.('ready'). Don't get confused with on click, on focus etc etc

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: click event just worked well after changing the ready code!

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, sorry, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation for [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), emphasis mine:

> There is also `$(document).on("ready", handler)`, deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and ***removed in jQuery 3.0***. Note that if the DOM becomes ready before this event is attached, the handler will not be executed.

Comment: The documentation of `on` no longer contains the quote, but see the release notes of `1.8`, section `Events`: https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/ references https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11719/ - just as note.

Comment: @FireEmerald the line appears to still be there for me.

Comment: Ah your'e right, i thought your link of the `on()` docu references https://api.jquery.com/on/ - but it link's to `ready` instead, a bit confusing. I should have clicked it, had the on page already open thus didn't checked it.

Comment: You're right - I labelled that badly. I'll fix it

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `ready` is not an event (*not in jQuery nor html*). It's a function that jQuery has created to determine the state of the document. So don't confuse this two things.

There are only two ways to use a ready state. By the `ready` function, or by a shorthand, what is basically the same:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});


$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first code below mentioned is not valid jquery.

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
```

instead of this please use this one.

```
$(function(){

});
//Or
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```