# Difference between jQuery.ready() and jQuery(document).on(ready)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Both examples below fire correct, when they are **included in the html** site as `<script>` block. But if both examples are inside a included `src.js` file, Example 1 fires **before** any DOM entity is accessible.

What's the reason for this? I thought `jQuery.ready()` is equal to `jQuery(document).on("ready")`.

```js
// Example 1: Does only work when placed inside html <script> block
jQuery(document).on("ready", (function($) {
  console.log($("h1").text());
})(jQuery));
```

```js
// Example 2: Works in <script> block as well as inside linked *.js file
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: just use `$(function(){})` and forget about `ready`

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Could you please explain the reason behind your answer and why your approach is better than Example 1 and 2? At least Example 2 works.

Comment: Similar difference between `$(selector).on('click',...)` and `$(selector).click(...)`

Comment: Because, as stated in the documentation, `on("read")` is deprecated since version 1.8.

Comment: `$(() => {...})` works too

Comment: There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. Note that if the DOM becomes ready before this event is attached, the handler will not be executed.  https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I couldn't find any deprecation note inside https://api.jquery.com/on/ about `on("ready")`. Could you point it to me and others?

Comment: See this accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651676/ready-working-onready-not-working-why

Comment: `on("ready")` was in fact deprecated in 1.8 see: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11719/ I was only wondering why the call worked in my tests partially, as i used jQuery 3.x, but in wordpress. My thoughts are that wordpress includes by default `jquery-migrate` - which may has some sort of backward compatibility, which hid that deprecation for me.

Comment: *"I thought `jQuery.ready()` is equal to `jQuery(document).on("ready")`*".  It is not.  There are some shortcut handlers that work this way, eg the aforementioned `.click(..)` => `.on("click", ...)` but this is not the case with `.ready`. FYI [learn jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) still suggests `$(document).ready(` but [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) recommends `$(handler)`  (eg `$(function() { .. })`)